# Get people where multiple rows are equal (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the sql schema like this:

```
ID    | Like
______|_______ 
p1    |   2
p1    |   3
p1    |   4
p2    |   3
p2    |   2
p3    |   2
p3    |   3
p3    |   4
p4    |   3
p4    |   2
```

So I have to Select pairs of people, who like same things. (In this example: [p1,p3] and [p2,p4]). All 'like' should be same, so [p1,p2] is wrong! 
How can I do that?

Ahead thank you for the answers!

Comment: can you please elaborate what you want as output exactly,till now i understand that you want two pairs from above query `p1,p3` and `p2,p4` because there all likes are matching ...right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a relational division operation. You can do this with a combination of NOT EXISTS clauses, e.g.:

```
SELECT a.ID AS ID1
      ,b.ID AS ID2
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM mytable) a
      ,(SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM mytable) b
WHERE  a.ID < b.ID
AND    NOT EXISTS
       ( SELECT a2.Like
         FROM   mytable a2
         WHERE  a.ID = a2.ID
         MINUS
         SELECT b2.Like
         FROM   mytable b2
         WHERE  b.ID = b2.ID
       )
AND    NOT EXISTS
       ( SELECT b2.Like
         FROM   mytable b2
         WHERE  b.ID = b2.ID
         MINUS
         SELECT a2.Like
         FROM   mytable a2
         WHERE  a.ID = a2.ID
       );

ID1 ID2
=== ===
p1  p3
p2  p4
```

Comment: Please note: I'm not sure that this is the most efficient solution. I've changed it to possibly reduce the amount of work required.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the Oracle version number you're using. In 11g you can use the LISTAGG analytic function for this. If you're using Oracle 10, you can use the undocumented WM_CONCAT function (please note that in some versions it returns a VARCHAR and in other versions a CLOB):

```
SELECT like, WM_CONCAT(id)
  FROM mytable
 GROUP BY like
```

Here's some more information on how you can do this:
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php

Hope this helps.

Comment: as the title suggest get people when multiple rows are equal ,i think he is asking for  `p1,p3` and `p2,p4` as output ,and your query will return `2 p1,p2,p4,p3`  `3 p1,p3,p4,p2` `4 p1,p3`